# Is there a quick way to determine the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In a problem set, we were asked to determine the eigenvalues of a $5 \times 5$ symmetric matrix. I know its possible to just find the eigenvalue, $ \lambda $ by calculating the values of $\lambda $ which satisfy $\det( \lambda I - A ) = 0 $, where A is the aforementioned $ 5 \times 5$ matrix.

However, is there a quicker and easier way to find the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix?

Comment: trace is the sum of the eigenvalues and the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues. Sometimes helpful. If you have a repeated row or column or any sort of linear dependence amongst the  columns or rows then the determinant is zero hence there is an eigenvalue of zero.

Comment: Also of help: the eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are all real valued.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook yup that's true. However, how about the other non 0 eigenvalues?

Comment: [This question is very similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816087/quick-method-for-finding-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-in-a-symmetric-5-times-5)

Comment: Sounds like a busywork problem, 3 x 3 would suffice for practice. As Trefethen points out in *Numerical Linear Algebra* determinants are rarely used in numerical algorithms, presumably because they are too computationally expensive. Axler points out in *Linear Algebra Done Right* traditional determinants are not necessary there either. See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359355/how-to-find-eigenvalues-following-axler

Comment: In my opinion there is no ONE quicker and easier method to find eigenvalues that fits ALL symmetric matrices.