# How to compute eigenvalues of graph laplacian?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, graph-laplacian

I know there are [various ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#:%7E:text=The%20most%20reliable%20and%20most,polynomial%20of%20its%20companion%20matrix.) to compute eigenvalues, and they are generally not very efficient for large matrices.

Graph Laplacians are symmetric and positive (except on the diagonal, which is negative). I see that [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816087/quick-method-for-finding-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-in-a-symmetric-5-times-5) gives one way to decompose a symmetric matrix into an easier Eigen-problem. Is this the best way to find the eigenvalues of a matrix (specifically a graph Laplacian), or are there others that people use in practice? How about the largest K eigenvalues?

Comment: 1. How big is your matrix? 2. Are the matrix entries mostly zero? These are the two most important considerations in choosing an eigensolver

Comment: @whpowell96 large, let's say corresponding to a graph with thousands or more nodes. symmetric, and let's consider both the sparse and dense cases. I'd be interested in any general statements and/or references if you've got any

Comment: Just $\mathcal{O}(10^3)$ is small enough that you cna probably just stick to dense methods. It will depend on your computing environment but most tools wrap LAPACK routines. You can browse some here https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node48.html

Comment: @whpowell96 thank you! This is helpful. Would you know about methods for solving eigenproblems of continuous symmetric operators?

Comment: Depends on the type of operator. They all reduce to discretizing via quadrature, finite elements, etc. It really just depends on context

Comment: @whpowell96 Would you have any resources? I asked a question yesterday: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4886699/computing-spectrum-of-compact-self-adjoint-operator