# Computing spectrum of compact self-adjoint operator

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, compact-operators

I know that compact self-adjoint operators [have a countable, orthonornal eigendecomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space#Spectral_theorem), and the spectrum is real and positive, and the only cluster point is zero.

What sorts of algorithms does one use to compute the first K eigenvalues of a compact self-adjoint operator? Is it similar to computing the eigenvalues for a symmetric matrix (like [these algorithms](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node48.html))? I know that symmetric matrices and compact self-adjoint operators are analogous in some ways.